# How to 'rotate' a matrix

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-matrix

I'm writing a pdf for class and I want to explain the transpose of a matrix. I want to add the following image to my .tex

[image]

Any ideas to work this? Should I delete this idea from my pdf?

Comment: Not TeX-related _per se_, but you may want to show your students [this comic](https://xkcd.com/184/).

Comment: @ArunDebray LOL this is so fun!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think you need TikZ for this (you can do for example

```
 \reflectbox{\rotatebox{-90}{$1$}}
```

and still use the regular amsmath matrix/array constructs) but here is a quick sketch

```
%%\usetikzlibrary{matrix} %<-Somewhere in the preamble

\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[matrix,nodes={rotate=90,xscale=-1},
    right delimiter={]},left delimiter={[},
    matrix of math nodes] {1&2&3\\4&5&6\\};

\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Also note that shuffle is not the right word there.

Comment: can you give me a example how to use rotatebox to get this "1" please?.

Comment: @LuisFelipe Try for example `\reflectbox{\rotatebox{-90}{$1$}}`